# Call both a template and a specialization for cross-validating results?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to build out test code. I want to call both template code and specialization code to cross validate the results.

For example:

```
// Function 1, "base" implementation
template <class T> int Func()
{
    // C/C++ code
    return x;
}

// Function 2, different implementation
template <> int Func<int>()
{
    // ASM code
    #ifdef __GNUC__
    ...
    #endif
    return x;
}
```

How can I call both Function 1 and Function 2 to compare their results?

Comment: If you want to call the first function for `T=int`, then it is not possible, because when `T` is `int`, the second function will be selected by the compiler (and you do **not** have control over  compiler's decision; that is too late). That is what specialization of template means.

Comment: @Nawaz `Func<void>()` calls the first one, so you can manually pick which one you want. `T` is not actually used in the implementation as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor out function bodies into functions with distinctive names, making original template and specialization just thin wrappers around them. This will allow you to test implementation separately internally (for example in unit tests) keeping interface for the user code clean and beautiful at the same time. Usually implementation details go into `details` namespace. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace details {
template <class T> int FuncDefaultImpl() {
    return 0;
}

int FuncAsmImplForInts() {
    return 42;
}
}

template <class T> int Func() {
    return details::FuncDefaultImpl<T>();
}

template <> int Func<int>() {
    return details::FuncAsmImplForInts();
}

void compareFuncImpls() {
    std::cout << details::FuncDefaultImpl<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << Func<int>()<< "\n";
}

int main() {

    // Internal testing
    std::cout << details::FuncDefaultImpl<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << Func<int>() << "\n";

    // External interface
    std::cout << Func<float>() << "\n";
    std::cout << Func<int>() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Func<SomeTypeThatsNotConvertibleToInt>()` calls the first function and `Func<int>()` calls the second function. Template argument deduction fails because the compiler has no way to figure out what `T` should be automatically, so you have to do it manually.

I would recommend you to use numbers instead of types though.

```
template<int implementation = 0> //leave out default value if you have no default
int Func();

template <>
int Func<0>(){ return 42; } //default implementation

template <>
int Func<1>(){ return 42; } //alternative implementation 1

template <>
int Func<2>(){ return 42; } //alternative implementation 2

assert(Func() == Func<1>());
assert(Func() == Func<2>());
```

You could also use an `enum class` instead of the integers to give the implementations names, but then you could just use regular function names instead of templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not doable. Assuming that you fool the compiler by making him call the general version(for example in a separate tranlation unit where the specialization is not shown) then the linker should complain about duplicate definition of the function.

Or does inlining come to rescue?